# convert python datetime to oracle number

Tags: python

How do I convert a python datetime object to Oracle number format.

```
datetime object:

datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 23, 0, 0)

need to be converted to number in Oracle,

20120923
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 23, 0, 0)
>>> d.strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20120923'
>>> int(d.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
20120923
```